# Declare package Class through variable - java

Tags: java, methods, package

I have created 2 packages with classes like

```
pakage1.class.files
  |- ClassA;
  |- ClassB;

pakage2.class.files
  |- ClassC;
```

But i want to call the code as follows

```
public class ClassC
{
    public void method1()
    {
        pakage1.class.files.ClassA var1 = new pakage1.class.files.ClassA();
    }
}
```

But i want to pass "pakage1.class.files.ClassA" as variable like

```
public class ClassC
{
    public string CL1 = "pakage1.class.files.ClassA";

    public void method1()
    {
        CL1 var1 = new CL1();
    }
}
```

Kindly Help me...

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this. Variable types have to be known at compile time.

You could use:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
Object object = clazz.newInstance();
```

... but then of course you'd have to use reflection to get at any of the members. You won't have a variable *of that type*.

EDIT: Of course you don't need to have the fully-qualified name everywhere in your code. You can use `import` statements for that:

```
// Please don't include "class" as part of your package name...
import package1.class.files.ClassA;

public class ClassC {
    public void method1() {
        ClassA var1 = new ClassA();
    }
}
```

... which isn't really the same thing, of course... but it may help you anyway.

Comment: Thanks Jon, But I couldn't get your point, can you make it simple please. ( I am new to java)

Comment: @user1629372: I've made it as simple as I can, really. You can't do what you're trying to do. You haven't given us any information about why you *want* to do this, which makes it hard to give any further advice...

Answer (score 0):

```
CL1 var1 = new CL1();
```

this is an error in java. CL1 is the identifier for a variable, not a data type hence you cannot use CL1 as a type when creating variables.